# Why does Wikipedia list an improper pronunciation of Esperanto?

Tags: pronunciation

The very first line of [English Wikipedia's entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Esperanto) on Esperanto proudly informs us that the name of the language is pronounced /ˌɛspəˈræntoʊ/ (and reinforces that using two common notations and an "alternative" which does not come much closer, really). In my opinion it couldn't be wronger. This is, surely, how an English speaker would read it if they knew nothing of the language, but *why would it be necessary to spell it out then*? For an Esperanto speaker this would be approximated perhaps by "Es-prenĉoŭ" which feels mildly insulting, as a non-attempt at even trying*. If someone told me they spoke es-prenĉoŭ I would be tempted to doubt the fact.

The non-trivial information here that would be appropriate to list in an encyclopædic entry should be how it is *actually* pronounced, which is something more like /ˌɛspɛˈrɑnto/ or /ˌɛspɛˈranto/ to my best knowledge. Why list anything at all if not this? I would put it in but

1. I'm not that well-versed in IPA,
2. I think there may actually be some reason why it is like this. After all it was very likely someone who knows the language that put it there.

*) Example ("Martina Navrátilová"): [This](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=H0XSZtfuq-8) is a very good attempt. [This](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=am2p5Dufb68) is just English and feels super inappropriate in something that should be primarily *about* the tennis star.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The English word for the language *Esperanto* is ‘Esperanto’ (written the same). The pronunciation of the **English word for the language** is given in the English Wikipedia. Just like how the name for the country *France* is written the same in English and in French, but pronounced differently. The English pronunciation in no way dictates how the word be pronounced in the original language.
We do the same thing in Esperanto. We say [be̞rˈlino̞] rather than [bɛɐ̯ˈliːn] for Berlin, which in English is [bəɹˈlɪn].

If we required that every country's language, name, city names, etc. be pronounced with the native pronunciation, then pretty much no one could properly pronounce most of the countries and cities in the world. That's why we give translated names to them. English lacks one or more sounds from [e̞spe̞ˈränto̞] (or [ɛspɛˈɾɑntɔ] or similar pronunciations), hence a pronunciation is used in English with the phonemes available in English (in particular [r~ɾ] replaced with [ɹ] and the [o̞] with [oʊ̯]).

Comment: Who says /–rænt–/?  I've rarely if ever heard it, even from people who don't know the word for ‘yes’.

Comment: @AntonSherwood I am not sure whether I understand you correctly, but do you think my answer is a rant? Sorry if this came across as such, but I merely tried to be as clear and informative as possible. The emphasis was meant to show the precise distinction and was not out of spite or annoyance.

Comment: No, I'm asking what English-speakers pronounce “Esperanto” with the vowel of “rant”.  I'm willing to accept that some exist but my impression is that they're a small minority (of English-speakers who know the word “Esperanto”).

Comment: @AntonSherwood Aha, misinterpreted that entirely, sorry. You're asking about things I never mentioned though, so that kind of confused me. Anyway, I reckon /ɛspəˈɹæntoʊ̯/ would be more common in the US and /ɛspəˈɹɑntoʊ̯/ in the UK. I don't often hear people say it in English, as I don't live in an English speaking country, so I can't be certain. I think I've heard both though.

Comment: @AntonSherwood Are you from the US? According to the Longman Pronunciation Dictionary it's pronounced /ˌesp ə ˈrænt əʊ/ in the UK and /ˌesp ə ˈrɑːnt̬ oʊ/ in the US.

Comment: @AntonSherwood British people say /ˌɛspəˈræntoʊ/. John Wells is a British speaker of Esperanto.

Comment: Thank you. Your example with France is great. Actually, very relevant to the question as posed, too: its Wikipedia entry starts with "France (**French: [fʁɑ̃s]**), officially the French Republic..." (emphasis mine). A [new revision of the Esperanto entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Esperanto&oldid=746927878) by Surfo (30/10) now follows the same pattern, leaving no ambiguity.

Comment: @LaVo You're welcome; glad to see I helped! Also good to hear that the Wikipedia page now follows that pattern; that should indeed thwart any confusion :).

Comment: @michau that sounds right; I live in the US, and I say "/ˌesp ə ˈrɑːnt̬ oʊ/" when I'm talking about it in English.

Comment: @kristan Interesting! I would expect that the /t/ would not become (partially) voiced [t̬], but even aspirated [tʰ].

Comment: @Joffysloffy I'm no expert in phonetics, and am not familiar with partially voiced sounds, but when I say it I don't *hear* an aspiration. But I was mostly talking about the vowels; particularly the "a". (Also I think the r would be more accurately ɹ, anyway, not r, more like /ɛspəˈɹɑːnt̬ oʊ/, but what do I know?)

Comment: @kristan Aha, I see. Perhaps it's just normally devoiced [t], but some people voice it, like /t/ in *pretty* could be [d]=[t̬] or [t]. (I also think you're confusing parentheses: slashes (/ /) means a phoneme, whereas brackets ([ ]) mean precise transcription. So /r/ represents the English phoneme usually realized as [ɹ], but could also become devoiced [ɹ̥] in words like *pretty*.)
I see! I thought Americans often changed /ɑː/ to /æ/ (e.g., *bath* is /ˈbæθ/ in the US and /ˈbɑːθ/ in the UK.).

Comment: @Joffysloffy "I also think you're confusing parentheses" -- Highly probable :-P. I read about the distinction once, but I forgot.

Comment: @kristan Fair enough! A while ago someone had to spell it out to me how it worked on the English Language StackExchange, so it's understandable :p.

Answer (score 5):

It is an English encyclopedia and the word is "actually pronounced" that way in English. The normal Esperanto pronunciation is given, too.

Comment: Where is it given? And a question remains: is the English pronunciation necessary? When reading the word Esperanto with English rules would there be any ambiguity?

Comment: Oh, turns out I was mistaken. I thought the "[espeˈranto]" was the "phonetic" English like in the first entry [here](http://thefreedictionary.com/maybe).

Answer (score 5):

As others have pointed out, the given pronunciation indicates how the word is pronounced *in English* (more accurately, in British English).

Is it necessary? As with just about *any* English word, it's certainly not superfluous to indicate the pronunciation. I'd agree that there aren't too many ways to get the word "Esperanto" wrong, but it isn't necessarily obvious which syllable should be stressed, particularly for a non-native speaker of English.